# Script run from crontab doesn't work

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, scripting

Running on the server I have a command that is started at boot as a service and it works well, now if I run the command that gives me information on the status of the service I get the data view, if I insert the same command in a file to have the output redirected to a file ( service status > status.txt ) and I run it in bash I get the file with the data, if I run the same file from crontab both as a user and as root I get an empty file! I've tried many ways but I can't get the desired result with crontab. Do you have any ideas?